# Comparison tool with easy line insertion

Tags: comparison, diff

Back in the good old days I used to use a tool for file comparison with one incredible feature -- you open file1, file2, see a difference, no magic here. But then you could insert an empty line(s) into file1 with one keyboard combo and into file2 with another keyboard combo. So you could easily adjust how C / asm function are aligned in case the diff engine failed to recognize similar stuff. Of course, after the adjust (insertion / removal of one or more lines in either file) the whole diff was "recalculated".

I fail to find similar features in diff, KDiff, ... I'd prefer a Linux app but I'm OK with a Windows app as last resort...

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Beyond compare (Trialware)

http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: Thank you, this is really powerful tool. It's true Linux version is only wine-based and it's not 100% what I wanted but it's good enough (its "Align with" option does its job). I leave this question open for some time, maybe someone else knows better tool, if not, I say your answer is good enough!

Comment: Beyond Compare for Linux is **not** Wine based, it uses Qt 3.3.  It does have another layer above that to make it closer to our Windows version, so it might not integrate into specific windowing environments as well as a KDE or Gnome app does, but it is a Linux executable, and supports Linux-only features like file Owner/Group/Mode and symbolic links.

Comment: That said, we don't get much feedback on the Linux version, so if there are improvements/polish you'd like to see, let me know, either here or at support@scootersoftware.com.

Comment: Thanks for the information, you're right, I got fooled by the Windows-like UI. Generally, I can't say anything bad about Linux version, it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

Beyond compare is best for comparison of 2 files